# When does the Windows 10 License expire on the free Windows 10 development environment

Tags: windows-10, download, hyper-v, development

The image(hyper-v) that I downloaded displays “Windows Expires Soon" Messages, although the download page says that it expires on 5/16/21.  I just **downloaded** and installed it ***yesterday*** on 4/16/21.

Does this happen to anyone else?

Any info will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the message being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

From the EULA

> 3. TIME-SENSITIVE SOFTWARE. The software is licensed to you for sixty (60) days from the date of
>    installation unless otherwise indicated in Exhibit A. You will not receive any other notice. You may not
>    be able to access data used with the software when it stops running.

https://windowsdev.azureedge.net/eulas/WindowsDeveloperVirtualMachineEula20151118.pdf which is available from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

Your license seems to conflict with the above from the EULA.